# Jquery fadeout - wait to complete - then delete <TR>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good evening all. I'm trying to do a fadeout with Jquery to a  with unique id which works but after that, i delete the  with simple function removeElement which works too. My problem is that the removeElement function kicks in so fast that you cannot see the slow transition of the fadeout. I tried using the Javascript native setTimeout function, but still no help.

```
var elem_comment_release_container = 'release_' + release_id + '_comment_' + comment_release_id;

//fade to <TR>...nice effect
$("#" + elem_comment_release_container).fadeTo('slow','0.00');

//removeElement(elem_comment_release_container)
setTimeout(removeElement(elem_comment_release_container),31000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove from the callback:

```
$("#foo1").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: +1. Just use the callback as he says. Exactly the type of situation it's meant for. It fires when then animation is complete.

Comment: thank you very much, that was so simple, i'm still new @ JQuery. I promise I'll read up more on it and come with challenging stuff :)

Comment: @AdrianTanase You're doing great, don't worry about how long it takes for some things to *click*. Before you know it, you'll be blazing through issues like this with ease. Welcome to Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: @AdrianTanase If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This awards the both of us reputation, as well as keeps the answer at the top for future users experiencing similar problems.

Comment: even if' i'm new at stakoverflow (which is an amazing website btw, with all the other portals at the bottom of the screen showing up) i was told to do so...but since i had to wait 6 minutes to click the check mark..i forgot last nite...here it goes :)